# Create new empty columns in R with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tibble, sparklyr

### Issue

I would like to create new empty columns with dplyr, based on a vector containing the new variables names. The columns I would like to create will contain only "0" for example. It is probably very easy but I can't find a solution. Ideally, i would use dplyr::mutates function (mutate, mutate_at...), because I need a solution that also works with **spark dataframes**. I would normally use mutate_at() but it only works if the columns already exist.

##### Note to those saying it's a duplicate

I can't use **tibble**::add_column(). I unfortunately need a solution that also works with **spark dataframes**

### Reproducible example

```
library("dplyr")

# --- trying to create 3 new columns
# I would like to do something like this : 
new_vars = c("var1", "var2", "var3")
mtcars %>%
  mutate_at(.vars = new_vars, .funs = ~ 0)
```

###### but it generates the error  :

```
Error in `tbl_at_vars()`:
! Can't subset columns that don't exist.
✖ Column `var1` doesn't exist.
```

#### of course, it works fine if the columns already exist

```
mtcars %>% 
  mutate_at(.vars = c('mpg', 'cyl'), .funs = ~ 0)
```

#### obvious data.frame solution but I need a solution that also works with **spark dataframes**

```
new_vars = c("var1", "var2", "var3")
mtcars[, new_vars]  = 0
```

#### obvious data.table solution but I need a solution that also works with **spark dataframes**

```
library("data.table")
new_vars = c("var1", "var2", "var3")
mtcars_dt = as.data.table(mtcars)
mtcars_dt[, (new_vars) := 0]
```

Thank you.

Comment: Do you strictly need to use `dplyr`?  What about `tibble`?  If you can use `tibble`, `tibble::add_column` would appear to be a solution...

Comment: Is there a reason you can't do `mtcars[new_vars]  <- 0`?

Comment: I don't know if it's really a duplicate, since this question says "based on a vector". I couldn't find a very simple way but this does it : `mutate(cars, map_dfc(set_names(new_vars), ~0))`

Comment: Effectively the same as @moodymudskipper but without `purrr`: `bind_cols(mtcars, lapply(setNames(nm = new_vars), function(z) 0))`, though frankly the only reason I'm using `bind_cols` here instead of base R `cbind` is your insistence on `dplyr`. So, a mid-`%>%`-pipe version is `mtcars %>% bind_cols(lapply(setNames(nm = new_vars), function(z) 0))`, easily fit into the middle of any pipe.

Comment: Yes I do need to strictly use dplyr.
I obviously know how to add a column in a data.frame... but i need a solution strictly in dplyr.

Comment: The reason i need a dplyr solution is because the solution has to also works on spark dataframes.

Comment: That's fair, I reopened it

Comment: Please try my solution above in the comments because I suspect it might work on remote spark tables too, but I'm not sure, please report. Try also `mutate(cars, !!!map_dfc(set_names(new_vars), ~0))` (same but with `!!!`, in case dbplyr doesn't unpack data frame cols automatically.

Comment: Or fall back to the boring but simpler : `for (var in vars) { df <- mutate(df, !!var := 0) }`

Answer (score 1):

I don't have `spark` available, but does an `arrow` connection closely-enough approximate what is needed?

```r
arr <- arrow::arrow_table(mtcars)
Reduce(function(dat, this) mutate(dat, {{this}} := 0), new_vars, init=arr) %>%
  collect()
# # A tibble: 32 × 14
#      mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb  var1  var2  var3
#    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#  1  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4     0     0     0
#  2  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4     0     0     0
#  3  22.8     4  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1     0     0     0
#  4  21.4     6  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1     0     0     0
#  5  18.7     8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2     0     0     0
#  6  18.1     6  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1     0     0     0
#  7  14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4     0     0     0
#  8  24.4     4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2     0     0     0
#  9  22.8     4  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2     0     0     0
# 10  19.2     6  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4     0     0     0
# # ℹ 22 more rows
# # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```